# In the following program how many processes will be spawned

Tags: c, unix

```
int main()
{
fork();
fork() && fork() || fork();
fork();

printf("forked\n");
return 0;
}
```

When we call fork function , the parent gets a **non-zero pid** while the **child gets a 0** in return
Based on this Logic, in the second statement we will have to apply the principle of **shortcircuiting**(afaik)....
After the 1st call there will be 2 process,

After the second line, 8 processes,[A parent gets forked two times in (**fork() && fork()**), and the second child also gets twice due to the "**fork()||fork()**"]

And finally 16(According to my reasoning)

Please let me know if this is correct or some other logic is involved

Comment: You could just count the number of "forked" and see for yourself if you are right ;)

Comment: Well, true, but I care for an explanation as well......And I dont want to tell the answer straightaway...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To calculate the number of process after (`fork() && fork() || fork()`), just remember that :

- In (`&&`) logical operator : **the right side** is evaluated only when the left side is **NON ZERO**
- In (`||`) logical operator : **the right side** is evaluated only when the left side is **ZERO**

And with operators precedence we wan write this like so:

`(fork() && fork()) || fork()`

Remember also that fork return **NON ZERO** to the *parent* and **ZERO** to the *child*

To simplify the explanation, we rename :

`fork() && fork()` operation **A**

and the **last fork()** Operation B, so the precedent line is equivalent to:

(`fork() && fork()) || fork()` => **A || B**

**First line** (`fork`) :

---> *2 process* (*Father* and *Child1*)

**Second line**:

- **A operation**:

the first fork =>

Father will give a child => *Father(PID of Child2)* and *Child2(ZERO)*
Child1 will give a child => *Child1(PID of Child3)* and *Child3(ZERO)*

We have *4 Process : Father (PID of Child2), Child2(ZERO), Child1(PID of Child3) and Child3(ZERO)*

The (`&& fork()`) will be executed only for last operations that returns NON ZERO => *Father* and *Child1*

Father wille give a child => *Father(PID of Child4)* and *Child4(ZERO)*
Child1 will give a child => *Child1(PID of Child5)* and *Child5(ZERO)*

Let's summurize:

We have *6 process* :

*Father(PID of Child4), Child4(ZERO), Child1(PID of Child5), Child5(ZERO), Child2(ZERO) and Child3(ZERO)*

- **B Operation**:

Is only executed for last commands that returns ZERO => *process that returns ZERO from A Operation*, Concerned Process are:

*Child4(ZERO), Child5(ZERO), Child2(ZERO) and Child3(ZERO)*

When forking this 4 process we end with 4 new process => `Total number of process after second line = 10`

**Third Line** :
It's just a simple fork

=> **The total number of process is = 20**

To demonstrate that: use this (`fork_quiz.c`)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        fork();
        fork() && fork() || fork();
        fork();

        sleep(10);

        return 0;
}
```

And compile it:

```
gcc -Wall fork_quiz.c -o fork_quiz
```

And run it like so :

```
toc@UnixServer:~$ ./fork_quiz & (sleep 1; ps -o "%P%p%c")
[1] 15455
 PPID   PID COMMAND
15046 15047 bash
15047 15455 fork_quiz
15047 15456 bash
15455 15457 fork_quiz
15455 15458 fork_quiz
15455 15459 fork_quiz
15455 15460 fork_quiz
15457 15462 fork_quiz
15457 15463 fork_quiz
15457 15464 fork_quiz
15458 15465 fork_quiz
15458 15466 fork_quiz
15459 15467 fork_quiz
15459 15468 fork_quiz
15465 15469 fork_quiz
15467 15470 fork_quiz
15463 15471 fork_quiz
15463 15472 fork_quiz
15462 15473 fork_quiz
15462 15474 fork_quiz
15473 15475 fork_quiz
15471 15476 fork_quiz
15456 15477 ps
```

Comment: I thought on the same line regarding shortcircuiting... I just forgot to consider that child2 and child3 would execute the B operation....

Comment: When you say "The `(&& fork())` will be executed only for last operations that returns NON ZERO" is it because of compiler optimizations?

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite the program a bit to count spawned processes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_fork(const char *c) {
    int r = fork();
    if (!r) {
        fprintf(stderr, "process spawned at %s\n", c);
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
my_fork("a");
my_fork("b") && my_fork("c") || my_fork("d");
my_fork("e");

return 0;
}
```

Upon launch you will see 19 lines `process spawned` so 19 processes were spawned as a result of `fork()` invokation:

```
~$ ./test
process spawned at a
process spawned at c
process spawned at c
process spawned at e
process spawned at e
process spawned at b
process spawned at d
process spawned at d
process spawned at e
process spawned at e
process spawned at e
process spawned at d
process spawned at e
process spawned at e
process spawned at b
process spawned at e
process spawned at d
process spawned at e
process spawned at e
```

**UPD:** Number of processes can be easily calculated having in mind that there is [short-circuit boolean evaluation in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Any explanation for the number of processes....How many processes would be generated in the second line