# How many threads will be created by given C fork code

Tags: c, fork

Consider the code given below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
int main() 
{ 
   fork(); 
   fork() && fork() || fork(); 
   fork();
   printf("forked\n"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

The question is how many times `forked` wil be printed. As per my analysis, it should be printed 20 times. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923661/1317018) answer confirms the same.

However when I run the code on [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/SJVHk64Z4) and [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/KLsPRM), they print it 18 and 5 times respectively. Why so?

Comment: Write `(fork() && fork())` and try again, e.g. `./bin/nforks | wc -l` => `20`. (and yes, you should check the return of `fork` for failure)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* site

Comment: this is might be somewhat academic problem, but that does not mean its do-my-homework problem. I have read the answer on related linked problem. I have solved the problem myself in somewhat different approach and also tried to run the code online. So its not that I dont know the answer and I have directly / blindly copy pasted stuff from some exercise. Also as you can see, same code has been put in the related linked post (first link in question) also and that post is well received .

Comment: To get a better handle on what is going on, include more information in the printing — specifically current PID and parent PID.   You could capture the return value from each `fork()` into an array of 5 integers and then carefully arrange to print that array as well.  Carefully probably means formatting it into a string and then printing the string as part of a single call to `printf()`; that minimizes the chance for interleaved output from different processes, which will be quite a problem unless you arrange for them to sleep random times or something. Consider using `wait()` in a loop, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your code don't create any threads.** These are called [Pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) on Linux and you'll use [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) (which internally uses [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)) to create them.

Of course, your code is using (incorrectly) [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) so **it creates [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))** (unless `fork` is failing). Notice that **`fork` is *difficult* to understand** (and to explain, so I won't even try here). You may need to read a lot about it, e.g. [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) wikipage, [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), and perhaps [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (both have *several chapters* explaining it).

You should handle the failure of `fork`. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323923/841108), there are three cases to consider for each `fork`, and you'll better rewrite your code to do at most one `fork` per *statement* (an assignment like `pid_t pida = fork();`)

BTW, you'll better flush standard streams (and the data in their buffers) before every `fork`. I recommend using [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) by calling `fflush(NULL);` before every `fork`.

Notice that each process has its own (unique) pid (see [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) and [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)). You might understand things better if you print it, so try using something like 
`printf("forked in %ld\n", (long) getpid());`

> when I run the code

You really should **run that code on *your* computer under Linux**. Consider installing a [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) (perhaps in some virtual machine) on your laptop or desktop. Notice that Linux is very developer- and student- friendly, and it is mostly made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code you can study.

> they print it 18 and 5 times respectively. Why so?

Free web services should limit the resources used by outside clients (on Linux, they probably would use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) for that purpose). Obviously, such sites -giving the ability to run nearly arbitrary C code- want to avoid [fork bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). Very likely, some of your `fork`-s failed on them (and since your original code don't check for failures, you did not notice that).

Even on your own desktop, you could not create *a lot* of processes. As a rule of thumb, you might have a few hundreds processes on your computer with most of them being [idle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(CPU)) (waiting, perhaps with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or a blocking [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), etc, ... for some IO or for some timeout, see also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)), and only a dozen of them being runnable (by the [process scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Process_scheduler) of your [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))). In other words, a process is quite a costly computing resource. If you have too many runnable processes you could experiment [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

Use [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) and [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) (and also `htop` and [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)) to query the processes on your Linux system. If you want to do that programmatically, use `/proc/` (and see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more) - which is used by `ps`, `top`, `pgrep`, `htop` etc...

Comment: ok thats something new to me. And if thats the case, I will like to know how many times `forked` will be printed.

Comment: Since `fork` can fail, the number of successes is not predictable in general.